# Opencart: i need to search any product inside subcategories

Tags: opencart

I'm trying to create a menu with buttons that can filter products by main categories

This query url finds products inside a category:

```
/index.php?route=product/category&path=61
```

i can find only a part of products with a subcategory search.

```
/index.php?route=product/category&path=61_72_73
```

I need to NOT LINK products with their category parents, so is there a way to search with a subcategory filter? 
I tried something like this:

```
/index.php?route=product/category&path=61&sub_category=true
```

But this doesn't work, it works only with textual searches like this one:

```
/index.php?route=product/search&search=chair&category_id=61&sub_category=true
```

Answer (score 1):

ModelUse 'Advanced Product search for OpenCart'. You can search sub categories and any filters you add (including custom ones) with it.

http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&token=460e88e8227b9d7e80466e026dbe1f64&extension_id=13605

I use it for a car dealer website with filters like year, make, model (and sub categories of those) etc and it works great for me.

Here's a demo link:
[extension demo link](http://demo.blissfulinterfaces.com/advanced_search/index.php?route=product/advanced_search&advanced_search%5Bmodel%5D=product%2011)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
index.php?route=product/search&search=%25&category_id=25&sub_category=true
```

25 is category id (which is not mandatory)
and search=searchterm is for a sting search in all sub categories 
search=%25 means all products

search field name has changed at some of past version try this for 1.5.4.1

```
index.php?route=product/search&filter_name=%25&filter_category_id=20&filter_sub_category=true
```

and see here 
http://demo.opencart.com/index.php?route=product/search&filter_name=a&filter_category_id=20&filter_sub_category=true

Comment: that doesnt work... it says that cant find % in my products :\
PS: i'm searching also a price filter... it can be done via url request?

Comment: What is your OC version number ? i added version 1.5.4.1 usage tested on demo site

Comment: in 1.5.5.1 syntax changed a little bit ... filter_name is replaced by search ... try index.php?route=product/search&search=%25&category_id=20&sub_category=true this returns all products in category specified with category_id and it's children categories.